# Objective C-Anonymous union declaration

Tags: objective-c

I am getting a warning for the below code if i declare this anonymous union.
Its telling that no instance or variable has been created.
If i create a variable for this union definition its working fine. 
Is it that anonymous union cant be used in Objective C.

```
@implementation rs

union{
   int a[10];
};

@end
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with that declaration?

Comment: Its like overlapping the memory.And eliminating the memory wastage. this union has some 4 variables declared in my program but i havent included it here.

Comment: Note that a union is similar to a type definition. If you don’t have a variable of that type, no memory is allocated, so the type is pretty useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s the same as in C. If you compile a C program with an anonymous union like the one you’ve posted, you also get a warning.